# Http error 400 with HttpSubStatus 607 without a reason

Tags: azure-web-app-service

in azure web sites logs,

we see from time to time,
http error code 400 (HttpStatus) with HttpSubStatus 607.
the description is empty for this HttpSubStatus.

can you help describe the reason for IIS logging HttpSubStatus 607?
what can fix this, as this is an IIS error, and not webapp ?

[image: see image of log summery in azure]

the internet is silent about HttpSubStatus 607.

Comment: Unless a substatus is recorded in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-administration-management/http-status-code it is likely to come from another thing than IIS. What's the web framework you used for this web app? A framework can define its own error codes.

Comment: it's installed on a windows machine (azure web app service) with .NET 4.8 framework.  an ASP.NET MVC web-app behind IIS

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#log-detailed-errors You can enable FRT on Azure App Service to see what exactly causes the errors.